# How exactly does MongoDB's add unique items into an array via $push and $each operators?

Tags: mongodb

I got the hang of using the `$push` with the `$each` operator to add items to an existing array.

For example, I update my existing document like this:

```
Collection.update({userId: currentUser}, {$push: {data: {$each: document}}});
```

Sorry if the syntax is a little confusing. I'm using this on Meteor.

Anyway, how does MongoDB know they are inserting unique items to the array, in my case, the `data` array.

My `data` array is an array of objects, that looks like this:

```
data = [
{name: "Name",
 score: 24,
 date: "12/3/2014",
 entryCode: "3234SG34"
},
{name: "Name1",
 score: 20,
 date: "12/4/2014",
 entryCode: "3004SG34"
}
];
```

Basically, the only way from identifying "uniqueness" us the `entryCode`, since there are multiple objects in the data array that share the same date. From the documentation, the $each operator adds elements that don't exist/that are unique (in the most simple cases). Does the same apply when adding objects to an existing objects array? If not, then how is it possible to update a MongoDB document and only add object entries that are unique?

Comment: by equality evaluation of the object passed. This means it is not totally unique, to do that you can do some query magic to test if the entry already exists

Comment: @Sammaye How would I go about doing that? Is there a callback that I can add somewhere in the syntax above?

Comment: One good way for your example is `Collection.update({userId: currentUser, 'data.entryCode': {$nin:['3234SG34']}},{$push:{data:document}})`

Comment: But it is normally better to avoid negation operators normally so inverse the query to add if the document cannot be found, cannot do that with the amount of code shown so that would be upto you

Comment: Only problem is I have thousands of entries so just excluding one code won't work too well.

Comment: You might find the subdocumenting this is not a good idea, but again I do not know enough so I am just going on the basics of what you say